# Удаление обработчиков событый

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, как можно удалить все обработчики события click кроме последнего?

[image: Обработчики]

Comment: Если они через `on` навешаны, то через `off` можно снять

Comment: мне кажется или у вас обработчики не на элемент повешены, а к родительским элементам и документу? если задача в том, чтобы они не выполнялись, то просто запретите всплытие событий через `stopPropagation` в вашем последнем обработчике.